# Mutilple files for the single code for RollingFile

Tags: java, spring-boot, logging, log4j, log4j2

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
    <Configuration>

        <Properties>
            <property name="LOG_PATTERN"
                value="%d{yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ss.SSSZ} %p %m%n" />
            <property name="LOG_DIR"
                value="/home/sangamnath/Desktop/log" />
        </Properties>

        <Appenders>

            <!-- File Appender -->
            <!-- <File name="File" fileName="${LOG_LOCATION}/app.log"> <PatternLayout 
                pattern="%d{yyyy-MMM-dd HH:mm:ss a} [%t] %-5level %logger{36} - %msg%n" /> 
                </File> -->




        <RollingFile name="RollingFile" fileName="${LOG_DIR}/batchJobs.log" filePattern="${LOG_DIR}/$${date:yyyy-MM-dd}/batchJobs-%d{yyyy-MM-dd-HH}-%i.log.gz"  append="true">
             <PatternLayout>
                <Pattern>%d %p %c{1.} [%t] %m%n</Pattern>
             </PatternLayout>
             <Policies>
                <TimeBasedTriggeringPolicy interval="1" modulate="true" />
                <SizeBasedTriggeringPolicy size="2 MB" />
            </Policies>
          </RollingFile>



        </Appenders>


        <Loggers>
            <!-- Log everything in custom package -->
            <Logger name="com.batch" level="debug"
                additivity="false">
                <AppenderRef ref="RollingFile" />
            </Logger>

            <!-- Log everything in Spring Boot -->
            <Logger name="org.springframework.boot" level="debug"
                additivity="false">
                <AppenderRef ref="RollingFile" />
            </Logger>

            <!-- Log everything in Spring Core -->
            <Logger name="org.springframework.core" level="debug"
                additivity="false">
                <AppenderRef ref="RollingFile" />
            </Logger>

            <Root level="trace">
                <AppenderRef ref="RollingFile" />
            </Root>
        </Loggers>
    </Configuration>



main.app




     public static void main(String[] args) {

            //in zip
    /*
         * logger.trace("Entering application...");
         * logger.info("Hello Log4j2...");
         * logger.trace("Exiting application...");
         * logger.debug("This is a debug message");
         * logger.info("This is an info message");
         * logger.warn("This is a warn message");
         * logger.error("This is an error message");
         * logger.fatal("This is a fatal message");
         */

        SpringApplication.run(BatchApplication.class, args);

        // outside zip
    /*
         * logger.trace("Entering application...");
         * logger.info("Hello Log4j2...");
         * logger.trace("Exiting application...");
         * logger.debug("This is a debug message");
         * logger.info("This is an info message");
         * logger.warn("This is a warn message");
         * logger.error("This is an error message");
         * logger.fatal("This is a fatal message");
    */
    }
```

I am able to create the zip file

Problem is
1) creating the two files 
2) if I write the logger message above the main method it is storing **in the zip text file**
3) if i write the logger message below the main method it is storing in the **outside zip text file**

Problem is
1) creating the two files 
2) if I write the logger message above the main method it is storing **in the zip text file**
3) if i write the logger message below the main method it is storing in the **outside zip text file**

Comment: This question is not clear at all.